# Fastest method for calculating index of element changes in Python list

Tags: python, list, algorithm, performance, dictionary

I have the following Python list: `[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]`. I want to create a function that calculates the index of element changes. So, for example, the method would yield this result for the above list - `[2, 5, 6]` - since the first 2 occurs at index 2, the first 3 at index 5, and the first 4 at index 6.

Of course, there are numerous ways to do this. I'll be running this method millions of times daily over much longer lists, so I'm looking for the quickest solution possible.

Here's the work I've done so far:

```
idxs = [i for i in range(len(inputList))]
dict_ = {v: i for v, i in zip(inputList, idxs)}
result = [v + 1 for v in dict_.values()]
```

However, there's a bug when inputting lists that have values that have been used previously, such as `[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1]`.

Comment: It will be hard to know what method will be fastest for you without a realistic set of example data.  You could get a better answer if you provided such a list or a way to generate a realistic set of data to benchmark on.

Comment: A little unrelated but if you're anticipating that there's a lot of repeats in the data and have to process it quite a few times, you could compress the list as a list of pairs, where the first element represents the value and the second, the frequency. For `[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1]` we'd have `[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 3), (1, 2)]`. Determining the index in which something changes is pretty straightforward in this case as well, as it's just the cumulative sum of frequencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could `enumerate` over your values and check if the `[i-1]` value is different than the `[i]` value.

```
>>> inputList = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
>>> [i for i, val in enumerate(inputList) if i>0 and inputList[i-1]!= val]
[2, 5, 6]
```

and with your second example

```
>>> inputList = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1]
>>> [i for i, val in enumerate(inputList) if i>0 and inputList[i-1]!= val]
[2, 5, 6, 9]
```

This will run in O(N) time which is the fastest this type of algorithm could possibly execute.

Comment: I wonder if zipping the input list with a shift of itself would be faster than repeated indexing.  It's hard to know without a realistic input example.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, but python lists allow random access in O(1) so that will likely not incur a runtime cost

Comment: this solution is correct however the question says it has to run on much longer lists, so maybe it would be good to mention that it is probably better to use a generator instead of a list.

Comment: Sure we're not hurting in the order of magnitude with list indexing but that doesn't mean we can't speed things up.  Having a solution that is O(n) overall seems like a requirement, but that doesn't mean that we can't squeeze out more performance from such an answer.

Answer (score 3):

So a little bit of profiling on some largish data suggests reveals some improvements that can be made just by avoiding checking `i > 0` each time in the list comprehension.  It's comparable to numpy though we're probably losing a lot converting to numpy arrays and back:

```
import random
import timeit
import numpy as np

max_value = 100
min_run = 100
max_run = 1000
num_runs = 1000

test_list = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
test_result = [2, 5, 6]

input_list = sum(([random.randint(0, max_value)] * random.randint(min_run, max_run) for _ in range(num_runs)), [])

def method_1(input_list):
    return [i for i, val in enumerate(input_list) if i>0 and input_list[i-1]!= val]

def method_2(input_list):
    return [i for i in range(1, len(input_list)) if input_list[i-1] != input_list[i]]

def method_3(input_list):
    return [i + 1 for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(input_list, input_list[1:])) if a != b]

def method_4(input_list):
    input_array = np.array(input_list)
    res, = np.where(input_array[:-1] != input_array[1:])
    res += 1
    return list(res)

def method_5(input_list):
    return [i + 1 for i, val in enumerate(input_list[1:]) if input_list[i]!= val]

assert method_1(test_list) == test_result
assert method_2(test_list) == test_result
assert method_3(test_list) == test_result
assert method_4(test_list) == test_result
assert method_5(test_list) == test_result

print(timeit.timeit("method_1(input_list)", globals=globals(), number=10))
print(timeit.timeit("method_2(input_list)", globals=globals(), number=10))
print(timeit.timeit("method_3(input_list)", globals=globals(), number=10))
print(timeit.timeit("method_4(input_list)", globals=globals(), number=10))
print(timeit.timeit("method_5(input_list)", globals=globals(), number=10))
```

This yields the result:

```
0.4418060999996669
0.3605320999995456
0.3416827999972156
0.2726910000019416
0.2845658000005642
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer using only `range` and `len`, without using `enumerate`, otherwise similar to the answer by *Cory Kramer*:

```
inputList = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1]
idxs = [i for i in range(1, len(inputList)) if inputList[i-1] != inputList[i]]
print(idxs)
# [2, 5, 6, 9]
```

The solutions are similar in run time, but using only `range` and `len`, without using `enumerate` is somewhat faster:

```
import timeit

t = timeit.Timer("idxs = [i for i in range(1, len(inputList)) if inputList[i-1] != inputList[i]]",
                 "import random; random.seed(42); inputList = [random.randrange(4) for i in range(1000000)]")
print('range + len:', t.timeit(100))

t = timeit.Timer("[i for i, val in enumerate(inputList) if i>0 and inputList[i-1]!= val]",
                 "import random; random.seed(42); inputList = [random.randrange(4) for i in range(1000000)]")
print('enumerate:', t.timeit(100))
# range + len: 15.435243827
# enumerate: 17.243516137
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use enumerate over zip:

```
L = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]

C = [i for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(L,L[1:]),1) if a!=b]

print(C)
[2, 5, 6]
```